# My program is printing all possibilities

Tags: assembly, x86, printf, system-calls

my program is printing all possibilities, It's written in Assembly I'm using the cmp mnemonic and the write system call(Linux). If I use printf, everything is working correctly so I think that the problem is in my system call not in the jumps.

```
section .data
    msg1: dw "Y > X",10,0
    msg2: dw "X > Y",10,0
    msg1_len: equ $-msg1
    msg2_len: equ $-msg2


section .text

;extern printf

global main

main:
    mov ebx, 10
    mov ecx, 20
    cmp ebx, ecx
    jc .xGreater
.xGreater:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg1
    mov edx, msg1_len
    int 0x80
    jmp .done
.yGreater:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, msg2
    mov edx, msg2_len
    int 0x80
    jmp .done
.done:
    mov eax, 1
    mov ebx, 0
    int 0x80
```

Comment: Some day, People may realize that x86 is just one architecture for which assembly code can be written.

Answer (score 0):

Your `msg1_len: equ $-msg1` line is in the wrong place, after `msg2`, so it includes the length of `msg2` too.

Learn to use a debugger.

PS: also, you probably want `db` not `dw` for the messages, and the system call doesn't need the terminating zero.